# Which version of Com.javaeatmoi.core compatible with spring 5.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, vfs

Which version of com.javaeatmoi.core:javaeatmoi-spring4-vfs2-support compatible with spring version 5.3.14

Current i have eatmoi as 1.4.1 but in the Vfs2PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver doFindPathMatching jar it has 2 parameter.
But spring PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver::doFindPathMatching has 3. This was working fine in spring version 4.2.5

Comment: Well judging by the name none... Appears to be for Spring 4 **not** Spring 5 so not compatible (anymore).

Comment: Yes. But as an alternate what is the version I can use for spring 5. This was introduced as spring removed support for JBOSS VFS2 in version 4.0. Do you know what could be used as a replacement?

Comment: No I do not, I only know this isn't compatible (I also noticed you asking a more or less the same question as you are using OpenAPI, you probably need to use a version that is compatible with Spring 5).

Comment: Yes. I am using openapi with spring. For that I had to use @component scan. But that got me into this trouble. I am not sure what to use as a replacement

Comment: A version of OpenAPI that is compatible with Spring 5... If there isn't you cannot use it. You also state you are using Spring Boot (according to your tags) and you should be upgrading Spring Boot **not** mess around with individual dependencies like that as that will break stuff.

Comment: I checked it is a spring project. Though the tag is there it was never used